# Getting Error while read the data from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, aspxgridview

I am displaying all the data in a gridview from database table. I have attached the database file in app folder. But while I am running the application I'm getting error like

> Cannot open database requested in login 'Employee'. Login fails.
>   Login failed for user 'HOME-47F64BE31D\Administrator'

Here is all my code:

aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="HireDate" />      
    </Columns>        
</asp:GridView>    
<asp:label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        GetData();
}

private void GetData()
{
    string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("GetEmp", str);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Please help me. What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is exactly what it's looks like: a database access error. That `HOME-47F64BE31D\Administrator` user doesn't have access to your database. You have two choices:

- To grant access to that user into your database. You can define that permissions through your SQL Management Studio.
- To inform a user with permission into your querystring; edit your configuration file to add a `User ID=aaa;Password=bbb` with a user with permissions

As side note, you shouldn't to use a `sa` user into your application.

Comment: Hi Mr. Rubens Farias,
Thanks for your reply...But when i installed Database i didn't set any userid and password. I have systme account password..what to do pls reply..

Comment: lets to create a new user to you: can you log into your database through SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Hi i am not using SQL Server Management Studio, i am using SQL Server 2000 express edition...

Comment: At Object Explorer, expand Security/Logins, right click-it and select `new login...`; enter `sumit`, mark `SQL Authentication`, enter a password and select your application database as default; in your database, expand security/users and to add that `sumit` user and to make it db_datareader and db_datawriter role member